# General : always saving settings on close vs saving only when changed

Tags: python, coding-style

I am kind of beta testing a small python app - whenever the app is closed the settings are saved, even when I made no changes. I was wondering if this is general practice - sounds like settings should be saved only when a change is made but are there reasons (apart from the reduced complexity) pro saving settings always on close ?

Answer (score 1):

If your app uses [configparse](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/configparser.html) for example, you will have the file rewritten if in the closing procedure there's somthing like:

```
with open('example.ini', 'w') as configfile:
  config.write(configfile)
```

It will be no different from before if you didn't change anything.

Comment: if your program fails after opening the file in `'w'` mode but before completely writing the file, you'll end up with a partially written file. the only way to fix that is to write to a temp; fsync the temp and rename over.

Comment: The mod time of the file will change - this sounds bad to me - I find it neater to have it changed on a actual change of settings - settings are in .dat files btw

Comment: @Mr_: Yes sounds bad, but not too bad. If *fix it or not to fix it* is the question, I think the answer depends on how complex is the program: if (a) is really simple: then I'd leave it as it is, (b) is really complex: I'd be careful for fear of breaking it, (c) is a medium project and that useless rewrite bothers me I'll probably write some modify flag sysyem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is even python related. In general you'll have something like this:

1. Load settings from file
2. Use and maybe modify settings in memory.
3. Write settings to file.

Detecting a settings modification would either introduce a change in 2 (keep a "changed" state) or in 3 (diff with the current persisted settings).

The first solution has little overhead (could be one boolean) but it is overhead nonetheless and it is in the "active" state of your program (not startup/shutdown). Also, it is additional logic that could go wrong (accidentally resetting the boolean to false on a copy for example).

The second solution has large overhead because you have to load a file, diff all the settings. This would actually slow down your code significantly compared to a simple "overwrite".

In the end you do all that work just to save one file write at shutdown, which is usually not the most time critical part of your application. If nothing changes you'll just rewrite the same file.

So I would not do it unless either storing a file is terribly complicated/slow or you really do not want things like "modify time" of the file changed unless you actually changed the settings. But these circumstances seem rather exceptional to me.

Comment: Hmm - I don't really care for the file writing - what concerns me is the change of the mod time of the settings file - seems neater to have this change on actual change - + some of the dat files are ~30 MBs

Comment: How about storing the crc of the dat files and on shutdown overwrite or not if the crc changed or not respectively ?